# Error In Excel Report Services In Share Point 2013. we're sorry. we ran into a problem completing your request

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint

I use `SharePoint 2013` and I want use `Excel Services Report` in `Performance Point Service`.

I have a SharePoint site that named `http://KSCOLAP`.

I deployed several report in my site with `performance point service`.

Now, I want create a `Excel Report` in `performance point service`:

I do this like below:

[image]

And then

[image]

And I config like this (for avoid of any error in my excel I use default sharepoint excel file):

[image]

And when I want view this excel file , I get this error in my browser:

```
we're sorry. 
we ran into a problem completing your request. 
please try that again in a few minutes
```

[image]

I follow all this ways in this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681487.aspx) , but I can not fix it ?

Comment: This question might find a more qualified audience at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my fault :

In Central Administration

[image]

Go to Application Management

[image]

And then in `Manage Web Application`

[image]

I select my web site (Share Point - 80) and then select 'Service Connection'

[image]

Finally I Checked `Excel Service Application` And it work for me.